# Find Differential Coefficient

Tags: calculus

Using the function of a function rule.

Question:

$$ y = {\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x} - 1} $$

My calculations:

$$ y = \sqrt {3x^2 + 4x}= ( 3x^2 + 4x)^{1/2} $$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {1}{2} ( 3x^2 + 4x)^{1/2}$$

$$^1 (6x + 4) = 1/2 (3x^2 + 4x) -1/2(6x + 4)$$

$$ \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {6x + 4}{2 \sqrt {3x^2 + 4x}} $$

This came back wrong for my assessment. Can anyone see where I went wrong, it looked right to me.

Comment: What is $y$? You've written various different expressions for it. Is the square root supposed to encompass the whole quadratic? Also the $-1$ disappeared.

Comment: Besides the rule is $\frac{d x^{\alpha}}{dx}=\alpha x^{\alpha -1}$, so you need to have $-\frac{1}{2}$ as an exponent.

Answer (score 3):

If $$y=\sqrt{3x^2+4x}-1$$

then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{3x^2+4x}\right)-\frac{d}{dx}(1)$$

so we have recalling $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)=\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6x+4}{2\sqrt{3x^2+4x}}-0=\frac{2(3x+2)}{2\sqrt{3x^2+4x}}=\frac{3x+2}{\sqrt{3x^2+4x}}$$

If its online software they're probably just looking for you to factor the two from the top and bottom to cancel.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look:
$$y=\sqrt{3x^2+4x}-1$$
Note that $y=f(g(x))-1$ with $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=3x^2+4x$. Now apply the chain rule:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3x^2+4x}}\cdot (6x+4)=\frac{3x+2}{\sqrt{3x^2+4x}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Writing your function in the form
$$y=(3x^2+4x)^{1/2}-1$$ we get
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}(3x^2+4x)^{-1/2}(6x+4)$$ so $$y'=\frac{3x+2}{\sqrt{3x^2+4x}}$$